# how to check if there a value between other values in a list python

Tags: python, list

I want to know if you can check for values in between other values in a list in python, for example:
`list = ['1', ' ', '5', ' ', '1', '0']`
In this case i want to check if there are any spaces between each of the values and if there isn't, join the values and make it one, like this:

```
# filter out the spaces and join the digits without spaces between them
beforeList = ['1', ' ', '5', ' ', '1', '0']
afterList = ['1', '5', '10']
```

Is there any way to do this? (I already know how to filter out the spaces, I just want to join the values without a space between them.)

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is good and fast for these kinds of tasks. You can create groups of non-spaces and then join them:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = ['1', ' ', '5', ' ', '1', '0']

["".join(group) for is_space, group in groupby(l, lambda c: c==' ') if not is_space]


# ['1', '5', '10']
```

This will have the effect of filtering out the spaces while grouping.